# A Multilingual shiny app using golem infrastructure

Tags: r, shiny, multilingual, shinydashboard, golem

I am working on a shiny app where users can select the language of the whole UI. That is, including menus of a sidebar object created with shinydashboard or bs4Dash.

What is the first layer of components I can update using select-input? (sidebar, dashboardpage, tabsetpanel...) ?

How can I make the menus of the sidebar reactive to the select-input widget?

I feel like shinyi18n is rather verbose, or I am using it wrong. Is it another method to work on this? With tabset panels for example? Using an external package with the translations?

[This repo](https://github.com/ColinFay/golemexamples/tree/master/golemshinyi18n) illustrates a convenient structure where you can change the language at the run_app.R level, but I don't see how to change it from UI (with a reactive for example).

[This article](https://www.r-bloggers.com/2021/05/using-shiny-i18n-with-golem-for-server-side-translation/) is useful but when running their code, I get: Warning: Error in $: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

I tried building something [here](https://github.com/AnotherDataGuy/shiny.golem.i18n). The translation works for content inside modules and all, but not for menus in the sidebar.

The app works fine locally, but publishing in shiny io returns an error of type 1. I suspect it is because of bs4Dash, but I am not sure.

Thanks !